# Saving file in Windows Folder from Python running on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am running a python script from Ubuntu TLS on Windows 10. I need to save a file to a windows folder. If it do e.g. from a pandas `dataframe`

```
df.to_csv("C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Downloads\\my_file.csv")
```

It just creates a filename `C Users XXXX Downloads myfile.csv` in the same folder as my script... (on the ubuntu file system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following

```
df.to_csv("/mnt/c/Users/XXXX/Downloads/my_file.csv")
```

Comment: I get : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @smallbirds seems I missed the slash character at the beginning of the path.